# Sonar Analysis takes too long

Tags: sonarqube

I am running Sonar Analysis for a legacy application in Sonar V3.7.4 
The profile setup in the server is Sonar way with FindBugs 
The size of the Java application:

```
Lines of Code - 5.7 million 
Classes - 20K 
Packages - 200 
Issues - 2 million (post Sonar run)
```

Since the codebase is integrated with Sonar for the first time there are several thousand issues reported by sonar code quality rules. For each run in the server, it takes close to 10 hours in the server. I am looking for an option in sonar analysis, so that the analysis is run in the server only for the changes made in the codebase . This way, I can integrate and report the overall issues for the application from the central server on a daily basis without running several hours for the complete unchanged codebase, whenever the build is kicked off

The following is the profiling extract  when the sonar is run:

```
Sensors execution time - 480 mins 
Decorators execution time - 70 mins 
Post Job execution time - 25 mins 
Persisters execution time - 20 mins 
Save measures execution time - 15 mins
```

The breakup of Sensors execution time:

```
Findbugs Sensors - 200 min 
Pmd Sensors - 160 mins 
Javasquid Sensor - 40 mins 
Cpd Sensor - 40 mins
```

The breakup of Decorators  execution time:

```
Issue Tracking Decorator - 30 mins 
Manual Measure Decorator - 20 mins 
NewCoverage File Analyzer - 15 mins
```

Is there anyway to optimize the sonar run time to get this done daily

Comment: We also have a huge system:
Lines of Code - >20 million 
Classes - 82K 
Packages - 6310
Analysis breaks with No space left on device with not all INodes consumed and no out of disk space